# Прилагательное от слова "паяц"

Tags: словообразование, прилагательные

Есть ли прилагательное от слова "паяц"? Если нет, то каким оно может быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Устоявшихся форм нет - видимо, такое прилагательное редко требуется, и речь может идти о применении по случаю. Не всегда словообразование от иностранных корней проходит гладко, например, для многих просторечно звучат такие разошедшиеся слова, как "шедевральный" или "барочный" (от "барокко"). Но в данном случае можно попытаться. Самое простое и безобидное - образование прилагательного с притяжательным оттенком, так поступают с самыми необычными именами и фамилиями. При этом сохраняются все буквы корня и отн. просто восстановить исходное слово. Розенкранц (из "Гамлета") - розенкранцевский; паяц - паяцевский (костюм, грим). Может понадобиться прилагательное и в значении "свойственный паяцу" (с уничижительным оттенком). Здесь можно поискать, как обстоит дело с русскими словами, оканчивающимися на "ц" (прежде всего, с ударением на последнем слоге). Купец - купеческий (размах); паяц - паяческий (-ая выходка). И ещё можно образовать сложное слово "паяцеподобный" (молодой человек - постоянно кривляется). "Паячий" хуже: обычно о биологических видах (барсучий мех, собачья шерсть, заячьи повадки, волчий хвост).

Answer (score 2):

Не нравится мне паяцкий. Во-первых это фамилия, во-вторых, не от паяца образовано, а от "паять". А паячий - совершенно не продуктивная в современном языке парадигма...

Я бы все же вообще поостерегся от прилагательного...

Answer (score 1):

Литературного прилагательного нет, но по аналогии с "зайцем" можно образовать "паЯцевый" и "паЯчий".

Answer (score 0):

пояцьев, паяцьин, поячьев, паячьин

Answer (score 0):

Самое удобопроизносимое - паячий (паячье, паячья, паячьи).
Не уверен, что данная форма литературна. 
Построение - по аналогии с заячий, кошачий, палачий (палач).

Р.S. В переводе одного из произведений Генриха Сенкевича, помнится, встретилось прилагательное "палачевский" (меч). Если это принять, то будет: паяцевский (паяцевское, паяцевская, паяцевские).